# using apply() when function is expecting the dataframe row python

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

My function is returning a value based on the dataframe row

```
def function(df, row):
    if df['A'][row]!='value':
        return np.nan
    else:
        return df['B'][row]
```

I need to call it using apply.  However, I don't know how to pass the row into the function.  I know there are more efficient ways of doing this, but the intstructions are pretty clear (yes this is a class assignment)

I have tried multiple variations of `apply()` and `lambda`.  Nothing is working. The latest attempt is this, but it's expecting a row argument.

```
df.apply(hourly_wage, axis=1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Shoot, I did the code block incorrectly.  Sorry about that.

Comment: `df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] != 'value', np.nan, df['B'])`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try : `df.apply(lambda row: function(row), axis=1)`
But you have to change your function :

```
def function(row):
    if row['A']!='value':
        return np.nan
    else:
        return row['B']
```